# How do I add custom fields to Survey and SurveyInvitation?

Tags: survey, salesforce-survey

I can't find a way to add custom field to Survey and SurveyInvitation. Where I can add custom fields to those objects?

Answer (score 0):

To add custom fields to SurveyInvitation, one has to follow link

https://login.salesforce.com/p/setup/layout/LayoutFieldList?type=SurveyInvitation&setupid=SurveyInvitationFields

To add custom fields to Survey, we could use link

https://login.salesforce.com/p/setup/layout/LayoutFieldList?type=Survey&setupid=SurveyFields

but there is no "New" button there.

The same applies to SurveyVersion, even if we go to

https://login.salesforce.com/p/setup/layout/LayoutFieldList?type=SurveyVersion&setupid=SurveyVersionFields

we don't have "New" button there as well.

Also, for SurveyInvitation, it possible to find this object in Object Manager. The link for Lightning Experience is the following

https://login.salesforce.com/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/SurveyInvitation/FieldsAndRelationships/view